# How to group by dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns in my excel,Session_Start_time and Time_taken. Session_start_time has date and time and time_taken has time taken to complete the session like below .

For example

```
Session_Start_time   |       Time_Taken    
01-AUG-2016 00:03:57 |        10    
01-AUG-2016 00:07:19 |        15    
01-AUG-2016 00:10:28 |        10    
02-AUG-2016 00:13:26 |        20    
02-AUG-2016 00:20:26 |        30    
02-AUG-2016 00:25:26 |        20    
03-AUG-2016 03:20:26 |        30    
03-AUG-2016 04:13:26 |        40    
03-AUG-2016 07:13:26 |        40
```

I need to group the session_start_time by the dates and have the avg time_taken for that particular day.

```
Session_Start_time    |   Time_Taken    
01-AUG-2016           |     11.67    
02-AUG-2016           |     23.33    
03-AUG-2016           |     36.66
```

Comment: Just use a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

You could add a third column that pulls out just the date of Session_Start_Time with the formula below starting in C2 and drag it down to fill:

```
=MONTH(A2)&"/"&DAY(A2)&"/"&YEAR(A2)
```

From there, you could create a pivot table with your new column as your row labels, and your Time_Taken as y our values.

[image]